# jQuery calendar - highlighting dates

Tags: jquery, calendar

I have a calendar that I have some dates highlighted

It works perfectly fine until I want to highlight a date after March 31st 2013. after that the date just appears as normal.

Anyone have any idea why this would be??

This is the code I'm using to highlight the dates

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[ 

$(document).ready(function() {
var SelectedDates = {};
SelectedDates[new Date('2013-02-14')] = new Date('2013-02-14');
SelectedDates[new Date('2013-02-15')] = new Date('2013-02-15');
SelectedDates[new Date('2013-02-16')] = new Date('2013-02-16');
SelectedDates[new Date('2013-02-22')] = new Date('2013-02-22');
SelectedDates[new Date('2013-02-23')] = new Date('2013-02-23');
SelectedDates[new Date('2013-03-01')] = new Date('2013-03-01');
SelectedDates[new Date('2013-04-01')] = new Date('2013-04-01');
SelectedDates[new Date('2013-04-11')] = new Date('2013-04-11');

$('#datepicker').datepicker({

altField: "#alternate", altFormat: "yy-mm-dd", maxDate: "+12M", dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",

    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var Highlight = SelectedDates[date];
        if (Highlight) {
            return [true, "Highlighted", Highlight];
        }
        else {
            return [true, '', ''];
        }


    }
});
});
//]]>  

</script>



<style>

div.ui-datepicker{
font-size:250%;
}

.Highlighted a{
background-color : #800000 !important;
background-image :none !important;
color: White !important;
font-weight:bold !important;
font-size: 22pt;
}


</style>
```

Comment: Strange, I ran your code and can't get any dates to highlight.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add this piece of css which I have added to the original post

Comment: I had actually created my own Highlighted class for testing, but the calendar still wouldn't highlight any of your dates. Can you create a jsFiddle showing the issue?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Jfyfr/1/
Im not used to using jsfiddle so its not displaying the calander properly but it is showing the correct dates higlighted up until April 1st

Comment: Got it to work

http://jsfiddle.net/Jfyfr/9/

Had the dates 2013-04-01 and when I changed them to 2013/04/01 it worked

Comment: As mentioned above, the following works: 

    SelectedDates[new Date('2013/04/11')] = new Date('2013-04-11');

Which would suggest the datepicker control is sending you incorrect values. Try putting a 'debugger' statement within 'beforeShowDay' and see what the dates come down as. It could be a datepicker bug..

Answer (score 0):

Think I found your problem..

The difference is the incoming 'date' variable.. The time zone switches between "GMT Standard Time" and "GMT Daylight Time". Put an alert on 'date' and you will see.